# Encountering different BSOD errors, how to fix?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I've left my laptop open while I was sleeping, then when I woke up it suddenly got problems when I tried to play a steam game (dota2 in particular, game is open but it's not displaying the screen. Background music of game is on and my cursor is the game's cursor). After that incident, I've been getting several BSOD to the point that I can't use my windows 10 anymore. Some of the errors are:

1. VIDEO_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT_INTERNAL
2. IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
3. DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION
4. VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE

Crash dump files can be downloaded [here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AIY-t-BThEH3d_o&cid=1A79967F548522D6&id=1A79967F548522D6%21584&parId=root&action=locate)

Hardware information:

- MSI GE62 2QD Apache pro
- Intel core i7
- NVIDIA GTX 960M
- intel graphics driver 5600
- 16gb ram
- windows is installed in SSD

**Here are some things that I've done based on my looking for answers across the web:**

- update all drivers
- tried the beta version of intel graphics driver
- fresh install of windows
- windows is updated

I know that the problems aren't going to be solved by updating my drivers, because as I've said, my drivers are all updated. Also, it's not because of virus as I've tried a fresh install of windows.

Some more information:

- Sometimes when installing a driver, when the UAC (I think that's what it is called, the one where it asks for permission to install) comes up, the dialog to accept or cancel doesn't show up but the screen becomes dark and desktop icon disappears. Example is synaptics driver for touch pad. Thsi problem doesn't occur in safe mode, but of course not all drivers can be installed in safe mode.
- Few minutes after booting to windows, desktop blinks once.
- my laptop has ubuntu installed in a separate drive.
- Ubuntu doesn't have problem. In fact right now I can't use my windows and I'm using my ubuntu.
- before the problem occurred I didn't install any program or update any drive

**Edit**:

I found out that the problem lies with nvidia driver. However, I've tried both old and latest version of the driver, so why am I getting a BSOD? Maybe it is hardware related?

Comment: report it to nvidia in their forums: https://forums.geforce.com/default/board/33/geforce-drivers/, but first really update the driver. your is from 2015 ( Fri Jul 31 18:54:50 2015), so try the latest http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/110601/en-us

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the reply. Actually I'm assuming right now that my gpu is dead. Those log files are from the fresh install of my windows where I'm trying out different versions of drivers. But I'll still try to install the driver from your link then report this issue to Nvidia.

Comment: if the new driver doesn't fix it and you think you have a hwardware issue contact the MSi support and look if you can send the device to repair/mainboard replacement to MSI.